# Best way to detect a small portable device in the range of 5-6 meters

Tags: pi-2, server, home-automation, rfid

I have a couple of things automated in my room (fan, lights etc) using a server running on Rapsberry Pi 2 and relays.

Now I would like to implement a system to automatically detect when *I* am in the range of the Raspberry Pi, namely about 4-5 meters. Using a portable device such as a bracelet or a small thing attached to my clothes is what I would like and then the reader would somehow detect when I am around.

Long range RFID tags seem to be an interesting option, but I couldn't find a good solution that is compatible with RPi... and also I am not sure if it is safe to use such an antenna in my room.

I am not sure about bluetooth devices that would somehow automatically connect when I am around the RPi either, but I think that the device that will be attached to me won't be passive anymore.

Also, using my phone which automatically joins the wifi network would be an option, but I don't take my phone with me always and the router has quite a long range.

What is the best and safe way to have a passive device with me that would trigger my presence to the RPi?

Comment: Interesting task but the Pi is irrelevant.

Comment: Well, you’re right, but where would be a better place to ask/migrate this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might look into a [Passive IR sensor](https://duckduckgo.com/?t=ffnt&q=passive+IR+sensor&ia=web). You don't need to carry anything with you :) They're extremely simple (hardware-wise), and many [relevant "How-To" articles are available](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=Raspberry+Pi+code+for+PIR+sensor&t=ffnt&ia=web) for interfacing with RPi, and coding examples. There was [another question on PIR sensors](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/117931/83790) posted here recently - you may wish to have a look at those answers.

PIR isn't going to identify ***you*** specifically - if that's your aim. However, there was an [excellent, well-researched answer posted here years ago that used the RPi for *speech recognition*](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/10392/83790).

And finally - there is facial recognition: RPi hardware several years ago may have lacked the *horsepower* to do facial recognition, but there are [several projects available today](https://duckduckgo.com/?t=ffnt&q=raspberry+pi+face+recognition&ia=web) that apparently [do that](https://duckduckgo.com/?t=ffnt&q=raspberry+pi+face+recognition&pn=3&iax=images&ia=images) rather easily.

Comment: Umm, I don’t want to detect when someone else enters the room but only when I enter the room (or specifically, that portable device). Voice/facial recognition would not be the right thing because I want it to be fast enough and not have to talk. Thanks!

Comment: @IonicăBizău: `a system to automatically detect when I am in the range of the Raspberry Pi`. Writing [good questions](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) is hard. You also didn't like the [other answer](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/119033/83790). Perhaps give this some thought next time?

Answer (score 0):

There’s some instructions you might want to look at here - https://magpi.raspberrypi.org/articles/create-a-raspberry-pi-3-bluetooth-tag

Comment: I mentioned this solution but I don’t take my phone always with me. I’d rather use a passive tag/device instead. Thanks!